# How to add nuget references to projects primary output for InstallShield?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, installation, installshield-le

I have a simple console app for which I need to create an installer. I am using InstallShield limited Edition for this.

The issue is that the reference for log4net (which I have added using nuget is not included in the projects primary output). Therefor the dll for log4net is not installed in the destination folder. Below are the properties for log4net.

[image]

Below is the primary output for the project. Note that this does not include the log4net dll even though it is copied to the output folder (bin/release)

[image]

I can add the reference to dll explicitly by using the add files button but then the path to that dll is hardcoded. What is the correct way to add the dependency here. Kindly add a comment if any other information is needed. Thanks for your time

Comment: I know it's been a long time since you posted this, but did you ever find a solution? I have the same issue, but with a different Nuget package

Comment: unfortunately, no